# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift2

Tags: swift2

let `responceArray:[JSONDict] =  model["data"] as! [JSONDict]`

> Error:- unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

in above line of code i am getting error where does it found the nil value

Comment: Either `model["data"]` is nil or it's not a `[JSONDict]`. You can't know because you're force unwrapping and you're not handling errors. I suggest you read the "Optionals" chapter in the Swift manual.

Comment: You are getting [JSONDict] nil as u you u mentioned as! It means you are sure it never nil But in your case its nil so it will crash. If you are not sure you should use as?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are casting `model["data"]` to the type `[JSONDict]`, the compiler isn't expecting that type so you should use `as?` instead of `as!`.

The fact that you received `nil` must mean there is no value for the JSON key `"data"` in your `model[]` struct. Try printing the contents of `model[]` to debug your program.